# How to assign array ABC to another array which size is 6

Tags: javascript, algorithm

e.x.

```
array1 = [A,B,C]

array2 = []
```

Is there a way to copy A,B,C to array2 by random order,  and two times?

like

array2   =   [A,C,B,A,B,C]

Comment: what do you mean by 'no repeat' and 'two times'?

Comment: What do you mean by "no repeat, and two times"? Those appear contradictory.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mzuuLwdp/3/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Array.prototype.concat()` , `Array.prototype.slice()` , `Array.prototype.splice()` , `do..while` loop

```js
var array1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
, array2 = []
, arr = array1.concat(array1).slice();

do {
  array2.push(arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1)[0])
} while (array2.length < array1.length * 2);

console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function to random sort an array and return a new array.

And then, you can call it twice, to generate 2 different arrays, and use `concat` to make them one.

```js
/*** Function declaration to make a random sort in an Array ***/
function randomSort(arr) {
  var newArr = []; // create an empty array that will be returned
  while (newArr.length < arr.length) { // until newArray is not fullfilled, keep the loop
    var rndIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length); // get a random index
    // see if the new array already contains the element of that index
    if (newArr.indexOf(arr[rndIdx]) === -1) { 
      newArr.push(arr[rndIdx]); // if not, put the element into the new array
    }
  }
  return newArr; // return the new array fullfilled
}

/*** Usage ***/
var myArr = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
// sort the array twice and concat the results
var finalArr = randomSort(myArr).concat(randomSort(myArr));

document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = finalArr.toString();
console.log(finalArr);
```

```html
<div></div>
```